# How can I get 2 properties from my fetch in my dictionary

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest

I right now I have:

```
 fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"realLocationName"]];
```

which gives me something like this:

```
self.dict=
    (
            {
            realLocationName = "some where";
        },
            {
            realLocationName = somewhereelse;
        }
    )
```

I want to get a second attribute value from cd in this dictionary but im not sure how?

I tried doing something like this but it just overwrites the realLocationName with locationID

```
 fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
 fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"realLocationName"]];
 fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"locationId"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the 3rd line:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"locationId"]];
```

you've overwritten what you'd set on the 2nd line:

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"realLocationName"]];
```

You have to set one array as `propertiesToFetch`:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [entity propertiesByName];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[properties[@"realLocationName"], properties[@"locationId"]];
```

I've used [literals](http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray-and) for creating and accessing `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.